# in_array com URL amigavel

Tags: php

Estou aplicando URl amigavel com explode, fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$url = isset( $_GET['url'] ) ? addslashes( $_GET['url'] ) : '';
$url = rtrim( $url, '/');
$explode = explode('/',$url);
```

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, já estou fazendo de forma dinamica, fazendo com que os produtos fiquem da seguinte forma:

```
http://localhost/produtos/camara-de-ar
```

> ESTRUTURA:

A ideia é que, quando não encontrar a url, no caso, o produto (ex.: camera-de-ar-teste), exiba a pagina de erro, e isso funciona perfeitamente. Porém, o erro já informado acima é apresentado antes da inclusão do arquivo.

```
} elseif($explode[0] == 'produtos'){ // se for igual a produtos
    if(isset($explode[1]) && in_array($categorias[$explode[1]], $categorias) || !isset($explode[1]) || $explode[1] == ''){
        include ("pages/".$explode[0].".php");
    } else {
        include("pages/erro.php");
    }
}
```

> O ERRO:

```
Notice: Undefined index: camara-de-vento in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 126
```

Apenas a linha 126:

```
 if(isset($explode[1]) && in_array($categorias[$explode[1]], $categorias)){
```

Ou seja: se existir[produtos] e a categoria digitada (camera-de-vento) existir no array $categorias, inclua a pagina produtos, se não, inclua a de erro.

Como já dito, tudo funciona.. A minha ideia é tratar a pagina de erro, que até então está sendo incluida, mas juntamente disso o erro já informado.

Comment: if(isset($explode[1]) && isset($categorias[$explode[1]]) && in_array($categorias[$explode[1]], $categorias)){

Comment: Olá! Tão simples e eu me matando.. era só verificar se também existia, antes de saber se ele constava no array.. de qualquer forma, obrigado!